# Switch to the next field when autocompleted

Tags: android, autocomplete, textfield, user-input, autocompletetextview

I have got a lot of AutoCompleteTextViews and EditText in my app, and i wanted to make user input a bit more easy :
I would like to go to the next field when the user hit the dropdown list.
Thank you if you have any infos about how to do that !

Here is what i finally did and which worked :

```
AutoCompleteField.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 

         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                 long arg3) {
            TextView nextField = (TextView)AutoCOmpleteField.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_FORWARD);
            nextField.requestFocus();
         }
     });
```

Comment: what did you try and whats not working?

Comment: i setted an onItemClickListener to my AutoComplete field, but i'm looking for a way to go to the next field now !

Comment: thank you, that's what i wanted ! I'm not experienced in android so that may seem basic !

Answer (score 2):

hey add this to your edittext xml

```
   android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

and add

```
   android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

in your last edit text to finish

Comment: thank you but is there a way to go to the next field programatically ?

Comment: first you have to identify whether the user has finish to write on current EditText...and this can be achieve by TextWatcher by checking with specific time interval but I think that will be not acceptable in user environment...may be user want to edit the same even after that specific time...The above option will add next and done option respectively in keyboard

Comment: Ideally i want to go to the next one when user clicks on an item from the dropdown list, and for the edittext, i will just use the options you gave me

Comment: ok just an idea can you try like when item in dropdown clicked/selected then set focus of the next edit text